# SUMPRODUCT if the lines were in a specific month

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have 3 Columns. They are:

> Date, QTY Sold, Unit Cost

I am trying to use a Sumproduct that multiplies the QTY Sold by unit cost as long as it is in the month desired. My formula is as such.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(AND('Product Detail Parts ALL TIME'!$F:$F>=Summary!A3,'Product Detail Parts ALL TIME'!$F:$F<A2)),'Product Detail Parts ALL TIME'!$P:$P,'Product Detail Parts ALL TIME'!$O:$O)
```

- Summary!A3 contains 4/1/19
- A2 contains 5/1/19
- 'Product Detail Parts ALL TIME'!$F:$F is the Date column
- 'Product Detail Parts ALL TIME'!$P:$P is the Price column
- 'Product Detail Parts ALL TIME'!$O:$O is the QTY column.

This formula is giving me an error. 
Any help would be super appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use AND this way, in an array type formula.

Change

> `--(AND('Product Detail Parts ALL TIME'!$F:$F>=Summary!A3,'Product Detail Parts ALL TIME'!$F:$F<A2))`

to:

```
('Product Detail Parts ALL TIME'!$F:$F>=Summary!A3)*('Product Detail Parts ALL TIME'!$F:$F<A2)
```

So in whole:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('Product Detail Parts ALL TIME'!$F:$F>=Summary!A3)*('Product Detail Parts ALL TIME'!$F:$F<A2),'Product Detail Parts ALL TIME'!$P:$P,'Product Detail Parts ALL TIME'!$O:$O)
```

One Note:  SUMPRODUCT is an array type formula and as such it will do the calculations of each and every cell in the ranges provided.  Usually it is good practice to limit the size of the referenced data to that which actually has data in it.

Comment: Thank you so much, Scott. This worked like a charm!

Comment: @Preston if it worked for you, please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.